# Is it idiomatic to say "Intellego" to assure the speaker you're understanding?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, idiom, conversational

In other words, when an English speaking person would say "I see" meaning "I understand what you're saying", is it natural in classical Latin to say *Intellego*, as in, maybe even more than once? If not, is there such an idiom at all?

Comment: Do you want it to be idiomatic in classical Latin or modern usage? It sounds modern, but you have the classical tag.

Comment: Two related questions: [How do you translate the idiom, I see?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2701/79) and [Translating “understand” in a conversation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5069/79)

Comment: @Joonas: Classical! Looking at the linked questions I would infer _intellego_ is more used in the negative, whereas _capio_ is most natural here.

Comment: So it seems, but there don't seem to be many conversational use examples of *capio* in classical Latin. If you think you've found a decent solution, you can always answer your own question!

Comment: @Joonas: Uhm, after some research on the word, I'm indeed not that convinced... I hope to see a better solution.

Comment: For what it's worth, my Rosetta Stone course from high school used the perfect *intellexi,* presumably to emphasize the stative nature of the understanding.

Comment: Not really an authoritative answer, but the myself and members of Latin Discord server I participate in typically use the words *teneō*, *capiō*, and *intelligō / intellegō* (interchangeably) to express something equivalent to the English-ism "I see".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Intellego.* and *Teneo.* are both used as stand-alone replies in Plautus and Terence with the sense of "I understand" or "I get it":

Both of the following are examples from the *Andria* of Terence. The second one in particular is useful because you can clearly see that it is being used as an interjection by the second speaker to reassure the first-- she literally interrupts him to say it.

"SI: rogitabam 'heus puer, dic sodes, quis heri Chrysidem habuit?' nam Andriae illi id erat nomen.

**SO: Teneo.**"

"PA: propera. atque audin? verbum unum cavĕ de nuptiis, ne ad morbum hoc etiam . .

**MY: Teneo.**"

Examples from Plautus:

"LYS: Primum ego te porrectiore fronte volo mecum loqui;
stultitia est ei te esse tristem, cuius potestas plus potest.
probum te et frugi hominem iam pridem esse arbitror.

**CHAL: Intellego.**"

"EP: Hoc quod actum est. egomet postquam id illas audivi loqui, 
coepi rursum vorsum ad illas pauxillatim accedere,
quasi retruderet hominum me vis invitum.

**PER: Intellego.**"

NB: I cannot find any examples in the PHI of *capio* being used as a stand-alone phrase/interjection in classical Latin with the meaning "I understand."